# parsing an xml file using xml module in python

Tags: python, xml

I am tring to parse an xml file using xml module. This xml file has multiple tags and some of the tag have sub tags. The xml file is as shown below :

**file.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="ObjectGenerator_DEBUG">
        <properties>
            <property name="id" value="9" />
            <property name="short_description" value="" />
            <property name="requirements" value="" />
            <property name="build_nr" value="2571" />
        </properties>
        <testcase classname="DEBUG" name="Test object creation" >
            <error message="failed" type="Error"/>
        </testcase> 
        <testcase classname="DEBUG" name="Init Test" />
        <testcase classname="DEBUG" name="Init Test2" />
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

I would like to parse the above file. While parsing i would like to only parse the tag with name "testcase" and their attributes "classname" and "name". Also additionally while parsing i would like to know if the testcase tag has an "error" sub tag. How can i achieve it? My implementation looks as below

**my_script.py**

```
def parse_xmlfile(file_path):
    tree = ET.parse(file_path)
    root = tree.getroot()
    for elem in tree.iterfind('testsuite/testcase'):// or for elem in root.iter('testcase'): 
        print (elem.tag, elem.attrib)
```

I am able to find only testcases tag but not error sub tag. how can i achieve this? Is there a possibility juts to check with every testcase tag if the sub tag is present or not. Tried both possibilities but not working. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following approach:

```
...
for elem in tree.iterfind('testsuite/testcase'):
    childs = list(elem)    # getting child nodes
    # check if `error` node exists among `testcase` child nodes
    has_error = any(n.tag == 'error' for n in childs) 
    print (elem.tag, elem.attrib, ', has error: ', has_error)
```

The output:

```
testcase {'name': 'Test object creation', 'classname': 'DEBUG'} , has error:  True
testcase {'name': 'Init Test', 'classname': 'DEBUG'} , has error:  False
testcase {'name': 'Init Test2', 'classname': 'DEBUG'} , has error:  False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for testcase in root.iter('testcase'): # loop all testcase elements
    testcase_att = testcase.attrib # get attribute of each element
    print(testcase_att)
    if testcase.find('error') is not None: # check if the element has error or not
        print("YES")
```

It will print:

```
{'classname': 'DEBUG', 'name': 'Test object creation'}
YES
{'classname': 'DEBUG', 'name': 'Init Test'}
{'classname': 'DEBUG', 'name': 'Init Test2'}
```